# SwaggerUI/YAML - reports: Should NOT have additional properties additionalProperty: requestBody

Tags: swagger-2.0

I am trying to define a swagger file but getting this error.

```
Schema error at paths['/ShipmentRequest'].post
should NOT have additional properties
additionalProperty: requestBody
Jump to line 20
```

I need to define that input is JSON in body. 
I have double check that I am not mixing formats between 2.0. and 3.0.

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 1.0.0
  title: ShipmentRequest
  description: The API enables you to manage creation ordes. 
host: myhost.com
schemes:
  - https
securityDefinitions:
  basicAuth:
    type: basic
    description: Username and password
basePath: /rest
consumes:
  - application/json
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /ShipmentRequest:
    post:
      summary: >-
        This is a request to create order of shipment. API is using
        API Key Authentication.
        Request will return JSON.
      requestBody:
        requierd: true
        content: 
          application/json:
            schema:            
              $ref: '#/definitions/RequestFormat'
      security:
        - basicAuth: []
      tags:
        - ShipmentRequest
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Success
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/ResponseFormat'
```

When I tried to use format described on https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/describing-request-body/ it reports me same problem but with property "parameter"

```
  parameters:
    - in: body
      name: user
      description: The user to create.
      schema:
        $ref: "#/definitions/User"     # <----------
```

How to properly set the consumer configuration?

Comment: To recap the linked Q/A: `requestBody` is an OpenAPI 3.0 keyword. In 2.0, you should use a body parameter instead.

Comment: Re: error with the body param - post the complete definition and the exact error message. Otherwise it's hard to say.